# Fixed point iteration VS Bisection

Tags: fixed-point-theorems, bisection

I need to answer a multiple choice question that goes like this -

---

Does fixed point iteration method **always** faster than bisection method?"

- Yes
- No

---

Now, I know that fixed point is faster, I have seen the math behind the convergence
But I wonder if there's like a specific case where I would pick bisection over fixed point ?
How would you answer that question cause I feel like I didn't get enough information or the question isn't well phrased.

Comment: The question seems perfectly clear and unambiguous to me, except that you seem to have omitted the word "converge" when you copied it.  What about it is unclear to you?

Comment: That's the thing I haven't omitted the word "converge" , its actually written exactly like that "always faster". when you put it like that I guess maybe there's a case i will find the answer faster with bisection?  you think they meant converge?

Comment: Then there's a typo in the question.  It isn't even a meaningful sentence.  BTW, I think the answer to the intended question is "no", since fixed-point iteration isn't guaranteed to converge.

Comment: Thanks like I thought it's not clear enough, I should ask from clearance from my teacher thanks

Comment: @saulspatz If we assume for each case we can use both methods, fixed point will always be faster?

Comment: No.  What if it happens that the fixed point is at the midpoint of the initial interval?

Comment: Amazing. Thanks buddy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116925/discussion-between-ygrno-and-saulspatz).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed point iteration is not always faster than bisection. Both methods *generally* observe linear convergence. The rates of convergence are $|f'(x)|$ for fixed-point iteration and $1/2$ for bisection, assuming continuously differentiable functions in one dimension.

It's easy to construct examples where fixed-point iteration will converge much slower than bisection (sublinear convergence). For example, the iterations $x_{n+1}=\sin(x_n)$ are well-known to converge very slowly, much slower than using bisection on $f(x)=x-\sin(x)$.

The main advantage of bisection is the fact that it is *guaranteed* to give linear convergence. The main drawback is also that it is guaranteed to only give linear convergence, whereas other methods can converge faster in some situations.

Bisection is also only applicable in some scenarios (the function must be defined over an ordered domain (e.g. not $\mathbb R^2$) and known to attain two different signs (e.g. not $x^2$)). It also does not give an analytic estimate of the solution, so it's less useful from a theoretical standpoint.